# Get Window title from PID

Tags: bash, process, kill

I want to kill a terminal session based of the pid and title name.

Lets say `pidof` returns **55175 as pid**, the window **title is TestWindow**, I've set it with `alacritty -t "TestWindow"`.

Killing the session is easy with `kill 55175`  or  `pkill alacritty` but this will kill all my terminal sessions with would be quiet annoying.

Is there a way to get the window title and its pid so is can precisely kill this session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On X one can, for example, use `xdotool`:

```bsh
kill "$(xdotool search --name TestWindow getwindowpid)"

# or

xdotool search --name TestWindow windowclose
```

Comment: Thanks, works just as I needed it to!

Comment: @Crylia Yes, one can do a lot of useful things with `xdotool`, `wmctrl` etc. Beware that sometimes windows can be nested etc (depending on program) - so one have to tweak. `wmctrl` can be easier on occasion. Also see `xwininfo`, `xprop` etc. (for example `xwininfo -tree -root` and `wmctrl -lp` )